# Advanced custom fields - taxonomy terms images

Tags: custom-taxonomy, images, terms, advanced-custom-fields

I used the [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) plugin to add a custom field to my taxonomy. That custom field is an image which is associated with the term. Now I have a page where I display a list of all terms (for example, car manufacturers):

```
$terms = get_terms("manufacturer_tax", array(
    'hide_empty' => 0
));
$count = count($terms);
if ( $count > 0 ){
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        echo $term->name;
        echo "<img src='" . $term->manufacturer_logo . "'>"; /* NOT WORKING */
     }
}
```

I wish to display the image associated with each term. How can I accomplish this?

**EDIT**

Here is the example result for one term:
`stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 5 [name] => Honda [slug] => honda [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 5 [taxonomy] => manufacturer_tax [description] => [parent] => 0 [count] => 0 )`

Looks like there is no image associated with this term. However, I can see the image in the backoffice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK had a go at this myself, I didn't realise ACF was able to add fields to taxonomies which is really handy so I wanted to figure it out too.

```
        <?php

        $libargs=array(  
            'hide_empty'        => 0,  
            'parent'        => 0,  
            'taxonomy'      => 'library_categories');  

            $libcats=get_categories($libargs);  

            foreach($libcats as $lc){ 
                $termlink = get_term_link( $lc->slug, 'library_categories' ); 

        ?>

            <a class="single-library-cat" href="<?php echo $termlink; ?>">
                <img src="<?php the_field('taxonomy_image', 'library_categories_'.$lc->term_id); ?>" />
                <?php echo $lc->name; ?>
            </a>

        <?php } ?>
```

It's in the docs here http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/docs/tutorials/retrieving-values-from-other-pages-taxonomy-user-media/

```
<?php the_field('taxonomy_image', 'library_categories_3'); ?>
```

So just replace the field name with your field name and library_categories_ with the taxonomy name. That should do it!

Answer (score 2):

Can you print the result of a $term so we can see what's stored?

I have used this plugin instead http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/taxonomy-images/

and the code I've used to get the image for each taxonomy is:

```
<?php

        $libargs=array(  
            'hide_empty'        => 0,  
            'parent'        => 0,  
            'taxonomy'      => 'library_categories');  

            $libcats=get_categories($libargs);  

            foreach($libcats as $lc){ 
                $termlink = get_term_link( $lc->slug, 'library_categories' ); 
                $thumb_url = get_option('taxonomy_image_plugin');
                $thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumb_url[$lc->term_taxonomy_id] );
            }
?>
```

But let's try to get it working with advanced custom fields first.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just updated my question with the result of a $term. I'm not sure if I could use the plugin Taxonomy Images, since I'm actually using two images for each term.

Comment: Have you tried just using the $logo = get_the_field('manufacturer_logo');

Comment: Yeah that's definitely an easier way to get the custom field, as that's the inbuilt API call for the ACF plugin.

Comment: Yes, I tried `get_field('manufacturer_logo');` and even `the_field('manufacturer_logo');`, and nothing happens. The image tag is there, but the source is empty (`< img src="">`).